# Is it possible to use an SVG for an ImageButton in Xamarin.Android? If so, how?

Tags: android, svg, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an SVG downloaded from the Material Icons site and I'd like to display it as a button.

```
<ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/buttonSettlement"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_black_24px"
          android:text="@string/settlement"
          android:layout_gravity="left"
          android:scaleType="center" />
```

Nothing appears.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Android doesn't understand SVG natively, convert it to png

Comment: Or use a `VectorDrawable`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible to use an SVG for an ImageButton in Xamarin.Android? If so, how?

Android doesn't support SVG. So it can't be used directly.

But as @Paul said, you can leverage [VectorDrawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/vector-drawable-resources.html). But first, you need to convert your SVG image to `VectorDrawable`. You can either use Android Studio to do that as mentioned in [this blog](http://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-working-svg-vector-drawables/). or use online converter like [this](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/).

After getting the xml file, copy it to `Resources\drawable` and use it in your `ImageButton` the same way as it was an image:

```
<ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/buttonSettlement"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_alarm_black_24px"
      android:text="@string/settlement"
      android:layout_gravity="left"
      android:scaleType="center" />
```

Comment: Is it normal that we can see the vector drawable in the axml file?

Comment: In my humble opinion it is not productive  to go convert online every time we need to include an ImageButton of svg source epecially if it was in shared code. It would be nice if Xamarin.Forms do the required conversion behind the scenes.

Comment: What did you mean `Android doesn't support SVG`?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try to use app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_alarm_black_selector"


Create "ic_alarm_black_selector" in your drawable folder 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_alarm_black_24px"/>
```

Comment: I got the error `Namespace prefix 'app' is not defined`, so I tried adding `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android-auto"`. This fixed the axml error, but the old image (a png) was still displayed on the screen.

Comment: Just add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" inside your  top layout..